# Can you set class variables in the constructor method parameters?

Tags: java, oop, class

Is it possible to set class variables by simply instantiating the class with parameters for the constructor function?

**Psuedo code**

```
public class Employee {
    String first_name;
    String last_name; // can this be set automatically from the parameter of the constructor function without having to explicitly set it?

    public Employee (String firstName, String lastName) {
        first_name = firstName; // is there a way to avoid having to type this?
        last_name = lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. You can initialise class level variables in constructor.

Comment: No (at least, without reflection, which I believe is not an option here.) At best, you can provide default values in the field declaration (`String first_name = "John";`) but you need to somehow instruct the JVM how to assign the values to the fields (you might want to swap the ctor arguments, right?)

Comment: @RaviG: AFAIU, the question was to automatically copy the ctor argument values into the object fields (according to the comments in the code.)

Comment: Your constructor is not properly defined, it should be just `public Employee` not `public function Employee`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to set it explicitly.

However, many IDEs such as Eclipse allow you to write your field declarations and then autogenerate constructors which set them.

(Note: I would suggest that you make fields `private`, and also `final` where possible. Also, avoid underscores in identifiers.)

Comment: *then autogenerate constructors which set them.* ... and then rearrange the parameters order [manually] :)

Comment: @bestsss: Well, Eclipse lets you order them manually before it generates the constructor, IIRC...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the closest you can get in Java as is is:

```
public static Employee createEmployee(
    final String firstName, final String lastName
) {
    return new Employee() {
        //  methods using firstName and lastName
    }
}
```

(where `Employee` is some relevant interface)

Shame really when you look at modern languages like Simula. ;)